# Prove $T$ is a scalar linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation of $d$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\Bbb C$ such that $T^n =I$ for some $n>0$. Prove that $T$ is a scalar linear transformation if and only if $|\mathrm{tr}(T)| =d$.

$\Rightarrow$ is almost straightforward. I want to show the converse but I don't know how to start. Can you give any hints?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then $\lambda^n x=x$ for some $x\ne0$, hence $|\lambda|=1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If all eigenvalues are identical, then it's a scalar linear transformation?

Comment: @love_sodam One way to approach this problem is to begin by showing that if $T^n = I$ for some $n > 0$, then $T$ must be diagonalizable. Do you know anything about the relationship between diagonalizability and the minimal polynomial of a transformation?

Comment: @love_sodam Generally speaking, it is not true that a transformation with identical eigenvalues is a scalar linear transformation. For example, all eigenvalues of the transformation corresponding to the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 1\\0 & 1}
$$
are equal to $1$, but $A$ is not a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes. $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots. In our case, minimal polynomial should be linear to be diagonalizable

Comment: this looks close to a rep theory problem.  An alternative approach to show diagonalizability of $T$ is to observe the custom inner product $\langle x,y\rangle_c:=\frac{1}{n}\Big( \langle x,y\rangle + \langle Tx,Ty\rangle + ... + \langle T^{n-1}x,T^{n-1} y\rangle\Big)$ is *T-invariant* (where $\langle x,y\rangle$ denotes the standard inner product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Proceed as follows.

- Use the fact that $T^n = I$ to show that $T$ is diagonalizable. What does this equation tell you about the minimal polynomail of $T$?
- As David's comment indicates, we can also deduce that every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$ satisfies $|\lambda| = 1$. We could also reach this conclusion from considering the minimal polynomial of $T$.
- With that in mind, show that $|\operatorname{tr}(T)| = d$ will occur if and only if all eigenvalues of $T$ are identical.

Comment: minimal polynomial should be a divisor of $x^n-1$. Since all eigenvalues are identical and $x^n-1$ is a separable polynomial, the minimal polynomial is linear. Hence $T$ is a scalar linear transformation

Comment: @love_sodam That's right.